# how to create drag and drop in wpf?

Tags: wpf

i want drag on treevieew one and drop in treeview tow

TreeView one

```
<TreeView Name="tvMain" FontSize="14"  Grid.Row="2" Background="#FFF9F9F9"  >
                <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                        <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="TreeView_MouseDoubleClick" />
                        <EventSetter Event="MouseRightButtonDown" Handler="TreeView_MouseRightClick" />
                    </Style>
                </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate >
                        <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image DragDrop.DragOver="Image_DragOver" Margin="2" Width="14" Height="14" Source="{Binding Path=ImageUrl}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" ></Image>
                            <TextBlock Margin="2" Text="{Binding Path=Name}"  MinWidth="280" Width="{Binding Path=SizeOfName}" VerticalAlignment="Center"  />
                            <TextBlock Name="lb_params" Text="{Binding Params}" Width="{Binding Path=SizeParams}" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center"/>

                        </StackPanel>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            </TreeView>
```

TreeView tow

```
<TreeView Name="tvMain"  FontSize="14"  Grid.Row="2" Background="#FFF9F9F9"  >
                <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                        <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="TreeView_MouseDoubleClick" />
                        <EventSetter Event="MouseRightButtonDown" Handler="TreeView_MouseRightClick" />
                    </Style>
                </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate >
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Margin="2" Width="14" Height="14" Source="{Binding Path=ImageUrl}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" ></Image>
                            <TextBlock  Margin="2" Text="{Binding Path=Name}"  Width="{Binding Path=SizeOfName}" VerticalAlignment="Center"  />
                            <TextBlock Name="lb_params" Text="{Binding Params}" Width="{Binding Path=SizeParams}" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center"/>

                        </StackPanel>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            </TreeView>
```

i have tow treeview
i want drag in treeview one and drop in treeview tow in wpf?

Comment: you can take a look at https://github.com/punker76/gong-wpf-dragdrop library which will greatly simplify drag drop handling in WPF. You can look at examples here : https://github.com/punker76/gong-wpf-dragdrop/wiki/Usage

Comment: You will mark first treeview as dragSource , second tree as dropTarget and create a drop handler by implemention IDropTarget interface and specify this as drop handler for second tree.. you can even mark both tree as dragSource and dropTarget and use same drop handler for them to drag across them.

Answer (score 0):

To enable Drag and Drop feature in TreeView control:

1. Set TreeView two control’s property AllowDrop="True".
2. Declare three events in TreeView control, i.e. “MouseDown”, “MouseMove”,
   “DragOver” and “Drop” events.

   ```
   <treeview.itemcontainerstyle>
      <style targettype="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
        <EventSetter Event="TreeViewItem.DragOver"  Handler="treeView_DragOver"/>
        <EventSetter Event="TreeViewItem.Drop" Handler="treeView_Drop"/>
        <EventSetter Event="TreeViewItem.MouseMove" Handler="treeView_MouseMove"/> 
        <EventSetter Event="TreeViewItem.MouseDown" Handler="treeView_MouseDown"/>
     </style> 
   </treeview.itemcontainerstyle>
   ```
3. And define event handlers for all the events in your xaml.cs file
4. Code for drop might help you.

   ```
     private void treeView_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
     {
          try
          { 
             e.Effects = DragDropEffects.None;
     e.Handled = true;
     TreeViewItem TargetItem = GetNearestContainer
         (e.OriginalSource as UIElement);
     if (TargetItem != null && draggedItem != null )
     {
         _target = TargetItem;
         e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Move;
     } } catch (Exception) { }}
   ```

Comment: It doesn't know 
 GetNearestContainer and  Effects compilers

Comment: You can define your logical methods. Sorry My bad, that example is with DragEventArgs. and GetNearestContainer is your function to find the nearest element you want to drop element to.